# Ошибка при переносе данных из матрицы во временную

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, матрицы

я попытался выполнить задание:

> Добавить строки после каждой четной строки матрицы

но у меня ошибка при переносе данных из старой матрицы во временную что я опять не так сделал?
Прошу прошения если вопрос плохо оформлен.

```
Line=line+line/2;

       int**tmpMatrix =new int*[Line];
            for (int i = 0; i < Line; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                {
                    tmpMatrix[i] =new int[column];
        
                }
            }  
              
                for (int i=0;i<line;i+=2)
               {
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                {
                    tmpMatrix[i][j] = Matrix[i][j];
                }
               }
               
                for (int i=1;i<Line;i+=2)
               {
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                {
                    tmpMatrix[i][j] = ((rand() % 10)); 
                }
               }
               
                for (int i=1;i<line;i+=2)
               {
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                {
                    tmpMatrix[i+1][j] = Matrix[i][j];
                }
               }
               
               
               cout<<"TEST:\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < Line; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                {
                    cout << setw(2) << tmpMatrix[i][j];
                }
                cout << endl;
            } 
        }
```

[image: ТЕСТ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не учли, тот факт что если берете четную строчку из исходной матрицы, то во временной матрице это будет строка не с тем же индексом, что в исходной из-за вставленной новой строчки.

Вот пример выходных данных с небольшим объяснением:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот пример рабочего кода:

```
Line = line + line / 2;

int** tmpMatrix = new int* [Line];
for (int i = 0; i < Line; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        tmpMatrix[i] = new int[column];

for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < line; i += 2, k += 3)
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        tmpMatrix[k][j] = Matrix[i][j];

for (int i = 1; i < Line; i += 3)
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        tmpMatrix[i][j] = ((rand() % 10));

for (int i = 1, k = 2; i < line; i += 2, k += 3)
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        tmpMatrix[k][j] = Matrix[i][j];
```

Comment: Да к сожалению не учел факт индексов ,спасибо вам большое за указание и объяснения моих ошибок.)